# Single table accross multiple DbContext classes using EF6 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In my application I have 2 contexts targeting the same SQL database. One context is for my AspNet Identity tables and the other one is for the rest of the application. What I am trying to do is make my 'User' table (which is for the `IdentityUser` class in my `IdentityDbContext`) available in my `ApplicationContext`. I am using Code First Migrations and do not want the `ApplicationContext` to attempt to create (or modify) that table - I just want it to 'know' about it and be able to query and join it to other tables but want it ignored by the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationContext, Configuration>()` initializer or when issuing `update-database` from the Package Manager console.

I have found a few similar questions but no suitable answers.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases I think, you have to create a separate `DbContext` That contains all `DbSet`s from all your `DbContext`s and use this master `DbContext` for migrations purpose.
If you want some entities be read-only in some your contexts(`User` in your case) you can define entitiy's `DbSet` as following

```
public ApplicationContext:DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; private set; }
}
```

`private` setter for a `DbSet` cause it can set by `Entity Framework`, but not by users.